# How can I create the input of raw transaction through the previous UTXO hash and the unspent index in bitcoinj？

Tags: blockchain, bitcoinj

I want to create a raw transaction’s input and output, and sign it then broadcast to testnet. Now I know how to create the output, but I want to refer the transaction that I can input the UTXO hash and the unspent index, then add the input to this raw transaction.

Answer (score -2):

here's how to create an unsigned raw transaction in typescript with one input and one output.

```
import * as bitcoin from 'bitcoinjs-lib'

const reverseHexBytes = (hex: string) => {
  const buff = Buffer.from(hex, 'hex')
  return buff.reverse().toString('hex')
}

const fixedPoint = (num: number): number => {
  return parseFloat(num.toFixed(8))
}

const outputAmount = 100
const inputTxHash = 'tx-hash-goes-here'
const index = 5
const fee = 0.001
const numOutputs = 1
const outputAddress = 'address-to-send-to-goes-here'

// input
const txInputs = '01'
const txHash = reverseHexBytes(inputTxHash)
const outputIndex = '0' + txIndex.toString() + '000000'
const script = ''
const sequence = 'ffffffff'
let tx = txVersion + txInputs + txHash + outputIndex + script + sequence
// output
const countHex = numOutputs.toString(16)
const countByte = (countHex.length === 1) ? '0' + countHex : countHex
tx += countByte
const amount = fixedPoint(outputAmount - fee)
const outputAmount = Math.floor(amount * (10**8))
let outputAmountHex = outputAmount.toString(16)
while (outputAmountHex.length < 16) {
  outputAmountHex = '0' + outputAmountHex
}
const outputAmountBytes = reverseHexBytes(outputAmountHex)
tx += outputAmountBytes
const pubkey = bitcoin.address.fromBase58Check(outputAddress).hash.toString('hex')
tx += '1976a914' + pubkey + '88ac'
// lock time
tx += '00000000'
```

check out the protocol documentation for more specific information: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#tx

note: i copied and edited from something i've implemented previously, so if there's a mistake just let me know and i'll update it.

Comment: Thank u very much for this answer，but I would like to implement it in bitcoinj instead of bitcoinjs.

Comment: there's only one line that uses bitcoinjs, everything else is vanilla code. you should be able to switch that out fairly easily, or look up how to decode a base58 encoded address to hex. the transaction composition part will be the same.

Comment: @j4ys0n Java and Javascript are completely different programming language, you can't just "switch" parts the code

Comment: @IgorArtamonov i realize that, which is why i clarified the language used. i assumed outlining the steps according to the bitcoin protocol documentation would be at least somewhat helpful.

Comment: I mean it's really different languages, so it only adds more confusion. With this example, to translate it you'd need to know TypeScript, JavaScript, bitcoinjs-lib and and how the latter use can be translated to BitcoinJ calls (which has almost no intersection in class names and methods). I would suggest to rewrite it to English, it will be easier to understand and apply to Java + BitcoinJ